# Where are "import from iPhone" photos stored in the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos, mojave, pages

Using Mojave on a Macbook while using Pages I found today the option "import from iPhone" which I used a picture I took with my iPhone to a Pages document in my Mac. I liked the photo and later I looked for it on my iPhone but could not find it. I googled a bit but found no information about this. Anybody knows where can I find these photos on my iPhone?

Comment: Your question is confusing.  What pictures?  Pictures you took yourself?  Pictures from some shared folder?  See [ask] for tips on asking questions including iOS versions.

Comment: Pictures I took myself

Comment: If you took them yourself, they should be in your Photos app.  Are they not there?

Comment: no, they are not there

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the `Photos` tab?  If you took a picture, and you didn't delete it from your iPhone, they'll be in the `Photos` tab.

Comment: I dont think they are stored anywhere except where you import them, in this case MacBook pages.

Comment: @fsb continuity camera might function differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The [Joe Friday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Friday) Answer:

1. The picture was never recorded on your iPhone. That's the way the "Import" and Insert features work in Pages.
2. You can get your picture from the `Pages` document easily:

   - Open the document in the `Preview` app
   - <kbd>control</kbd>-`click` on the picture, then select `Share`, `Add to Photos`. From there, you can export if you wish.

#### The Long Answer:

As I understand your question:

- You imported a picture you took on your iPhone to your Mac.
- You inserted that picture into a document you created on your Mac using the `Pages` app.

Your question is ambiguous with respect to whether you "imported" the picture directly into the `Pages` app, or if you imported the picture from your phone to your Mac using some other (e.g. `Photos`) app.

You may ask, "Why do I say your question is ambiguous?" Part of the reason is your wording (though certainly this subject is arcane), but the main reason is that the **`Import`**`from iPhone` item in the `Pages` menu is only available when you have selected an image that already exists in your `Pages` document. If your insertion point (i-beam, whatever) is at a blank spot in the document, then the menu item is **`Insert`**`from iPhone`. At least, this is the behavior that I see - your experience may differ. And so, if one uses `Pages` only occasionally (as I do), one might wonder if you got this mixed up with the Import feature in `Photos` (which always uses the word **`Import`**. But in any case...

1. If you "**Imported**" or "**Inserted**" directly from iPhone to the `Pages` document: The picture was never recorded on your iPhone. Sorry, but this is just the way the "**Import**" and **Insert** features work in `Pages`; apparently that's *by design*.
2. If you imported from your iPhone to your Mac using the `Photos` app, then there is most certainly an option to delete from the iPhone, or to retain the image on your iPhone. If this is what you did, then *you* have selected the option to delete it after the import! And AFAIK, you don't get a "do-over" for that; the picture is no longer on your iPhone.

And so, as to the location of your "missing" picture, it is in one of two places:

1. If you imported the picture from your iPhone to your Mac using `Photos`, you can find it in your `Photos` app on your Mac, or in "iCloud" if you use that option. You can also `export` it from there if you like, again using the `Photos` app.
2. It exists only in your `Pages` document. Again, not a big `Pages` user, but I'd guess there is some way to save or export the picture from the document. If you can't locate a better method, a couple of fall-back approaches are:

   - Do a screen capture of the photo in your `Pages` document (<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>).
   - Open the `Pages` document in the `Preview` app. From `Preview`, you can <kbd>control</kbd>-`click` on the picture, and then select `Share`, `Add to Photos` to add it back to the `Photos` app database - where you may have expected to find it in the first place!  :)

Comment: Hallelujah. Nice edit. Btw., for some reason, on my machine Pages shows "Import …" even in a blank document.

Answer (score 3):

When using "Import from iPhone" (same for "Import from iPad"), the captured photo is **never** saved on the iDevice **nor** is it saved somewhere on the Mac, say, in the Photos.app.
It only exists in the document you captured into.

To get the image, select the image in Pages, go to the *Image* tab in the *Format* sidebar, then drag the image icon or image title above the *Replace* button and drop to the Finder Desktop.

Please be aware that this photo is not captured with the full resolution of the iDevice camera (apparently downscaled to 1920px for the longer dimension).

Answer (score 2):

When you click Import from iPhone it does not save the photo on your iPhone, only wherever you import it to on your Mac.